# Changing a member of a structure

Tags: c

I'm having trouble with case 3 in my assignment which is supposed to ask the user the employee ID of the the employee whose salary they wish to update. The for loop searches for the employee ID and then prints out the corresponding salary.

Then "Enter new salary" is printed but for some reason my scanf is being skipped and it goes out of the case before the user can input the new salary.

edit: after adding a space before format specifier to ignore whitespace as some suggested(thanks!) user is now prompted to enter new salary but when i use option 1 to display the table employee 333s salary is unchanged, still displays the previously entered salary not the new one that was just input by the user

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS

#include <stdio.h>
// Define Number of Employees "SIZE" to be 2
#define SIZE 4  

// Declare Struct Employee 
// Empinfo.h

struct Empinfo
{
    int IDNo;
    int age;
    double salary;
};

/* main program */
int main(void)
{
    int i;
    int count = 0;
    int option = 0;
    int empIDcheck = 0;

    // Declare a struct Employee array "emp" with SIZE elements 
    // and initialize all elements to zero
    struct Empinfo emp[SIZE] = { {0} };

    printf("---=== EMPLOYEE DATA ===---\n\n");

    do
    {
        // Print the option list
        printf("1. Display Employee Information\n");
        printf("2. Add Employee\n");
        printf("3. Update Employee Salary\n");
        printf("4. Remove Employee\n");
        printf("0. Exit\n\n");
        printf("Please select from the above options: ");

        // Capture input to option variable
        scanf("%d", &option);
        printf("\n");

        switch (option)
        {
        case 0: // Exit the program

            printf("Exiting Employee Data Program. Good Bye!!!\n");
            break;

        case 1: // Display Employee Data
                // @IN-LAB

            printf("EMP ID  EMP AGE EMP SALARY\n");
            printf("======  ======= ==========\n");
            for (i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
            {
                printf("%6d%9d%11.2lf\n", emp[i].IDNo, emp[i].age, emp[i].salary);
            }
            printf("\n");
            // Use "%6d%9d%11.2lf" formatting in a   
            // printf statement to display
            // employee id, age and salary of 
            // all  employees using a loop construct 

            // The loop construct will be run for SIZE times 
            // and will only display Employee data 
            // where the EmployeeID is > 0

            break;

        case 2: // Adding Employee
                // @IN-LAB

            printf("Adding Employee\n");
            printf("===============\n");

            // Check for limits on the array and add employee 
            // data accordingly. 
            if (count < SIZE)
            {
                printf("Enter Employee ID: ");
                scanf("%d", &emp[count].IDNo);
                printf("Enter Employee Age: ");
                scanf("%d", &emp[count].age);
                printf("Enter Employee Salary: ");
                scanf("%lf", &emp[count].salary);
                printf("\n");
                count++;
            }
            else
            {
                printf("ERROR!!! Maximum Number of Employees Reached\n");
                printf("\n");
            }


            break;

        case 3:
            printf("Update Employee Salary\n");
            printf("======================\n");
            int found = 1;

            do {
                printf("Enter Employee ID: ");
                scanf("%d", &empIDcheck);
                for (i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
                {
                    if (empIDcheck == emp[i].IDNo) {
                        found = 0;
                        printf("The current salary is %.2lf\n", emp[i].salary);
                    }

                }
                if (found == 0) {
                    printf("Enter Employee New Salary: ");
                    scanf("%.2lf", &emp[i].salary);
                }
                if (found == 1)
                    printf("*** ERROR Employee ID not found! ***\n");
            } while (found == 1);

            break;

        default:
            printf("ERROR: Incorrect Option: Try Again\n\n");
        }

    } while (option != 0);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I suggest you do some [rubber duck debugging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) on your code. Especially the loop where you try to find the employee id. Hint: What happens next after the employee id is found?

Comment: Note that setting `int found = 1;` and then `if (found == 1) printf("*** ERROR Employee ID not found\n");` is non-idiomatic C.  Use `0` for false (not found) and `1` for true (found).  What you've got is not directly wrong, but it is confusing to anyone used to the conventions of C.

Comment: On an unrelated note, the logic of the `found` variable seems reversed. Basically, `found` is *true* if nothing is found, and *false* when you find something.

Comment: thank you I have switched the 1 and 0, actually I had that originally but I changed it when I was trying everything to fix the issue lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

following code has an issue, you are letting `for` completing the loop
  so value of `i` is same as SIZE now so it is out of bound for an array,
  correct it and have single space before format specifier, see if it works

```
 do {
            printf("Enter Employee ID: ");
            scanf("%d", &empIDcheck);
            for (i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
            {
                if (empIDcheck == emp[i].IDNo) {
                    found = 0;
                    printf("The current salary is %.2lf\n", emp[i].salary);
                     ======== <<<<< need the break here>>>>>> ======
                }

            }
            if (found == 0) {
                printf("Enter Employee New Salary: ");
                scanf("%.2lf", &emp[i].salary);  ========> i is going out of bound
                    and try with having <space> before format like " %.2lf" and see if it helps
            }
```

Comment: thank you, after adding the space before format specifier the program allowed the user input of new salary. unfortunately I seem to have another issue in my code because once the new salary is entered the program goes into an endless loop of displaying the menu options then immediately saying error incorrect option try again then back to the menu then error message again and so on and so on

Comment: actually i fixed that issue the problem now is that the new salary entered by the user does not replace the old one. help please.

Comment: @sam If it is not updating value, looks something wrong with format specifier `%.2lf` can you change `%.2lf` to `%lf` and try, it would work

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with the loop where you look for `empIDcheck`:

```
for (i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
{
     if (empIDcheck == emp[i].IDNo) {
         found = 0;
         printf("The current salary is %.2lf\n", emp[i].salary);
     }
}
```

When you find the correct element in the array, you don't end the loop but continue iterating. That means the value of `i` after the loop will be equal to `SIZE`, which is out of bounds for the array.

You need to stop looping once you find the correct element. This can be done either with the `break` statement:

```
for (i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
{
     if (empIDcheck == emp[i].IDNo) {
         found = 0;
         printf("The current salary is %.2lf\n", emp[i].salary);
         break;  // Done with the loop
     }
}
```

Or by updating the loop condition to check `found`:

```
for (i = 0; i < SIZE && found != 0; i++)
{
     if (empIDcheck == emp[i].IDNo) {
         found = 0;
         printf("The current salary is %.2lf\n", emp[i].salary);
     }
}
```

Comment: thanks I have added && found != 0 to the loop condition